# How Can I create an hierarchy (not tree model) representation in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I have some data in collection from which i have to create hierarchy diagram in Flex. Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  I'm afraid, you also have to read the FAQ or http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to find out how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow.  Yours is probably not going to make a lot of people write an answer...

Comment: I don't see any plausible way of displaying hierarchical data except in a tree-like structure. Post some codes/sample data which you would want to achieve for this.

Answer (score 0):

May I point you to TourDeFlex? There is a bunch of examples on how to do this. Personally I went for SpringGraph. It is free, sexy, did a nice job, and it was able to display hierarchal graphs (not only trees) which is exactly what I needed due to the circular dependancies my data had.

Comment: SpringGraph is not available in tourdeflex. Could you please share the source code with me?

Comment: I see that mark shepard's website is non-existing anymore. After a google I found http://code.google.com/p/openfca/. I also see that somebody shared it at http://www.gooya1.com/SpringGraph/.